# Migration from DotClear: rewrite urls of feeds

Tags: nginx, wordpress, rewrite

I've migrated my blog from DotClear2 to WP3.

I would like to add some URL rewriting on my NGinx configuration file, so that people who were following my blog using the RSS can still do the same without having to change the address in their aggregator.

The previous URL was: http://www.emidee.net/blog/index.php/feed/atom while the new one is: http://www.emidee.net/index.php/feed/atom

How could I write a rewrite rule in NGINX so that it automatically transfers to the new URL?

In short, I'd like to get rid of the /blog/ word in the URL.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably also remove that extra `/index.php` from your URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some unsuccessful tries, this one seems to be working well

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.emidee.net emidee.net;
    root /var/www/http/emidee;

    include global.conf.d/restrictions.conf;
    include global.conf.d/wordpress.conf;

    rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ $scheme://$server_name$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
server {
  # more code ...
  location / {
    # more code ...
    location ~* ^/blog/([a-z0-9\.]+)$ {
      return 301 $scheme://$server_name$1;
    }
    # more code ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I'm not redirected to http://www.emidee.net/index.php/feed/atom when I access http://www.emidee.net/blog/index.php/feed/atom Is there a way to debug what's going on under the hood?

Comment: You can always activate debug logging, then nginx logs exactly what it's doing. But the rewrite rule you posted seems just fine. :)